# js Download pdf file from given url but some files dont download proper

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I search a keyword on scholar and when page comes i get all divs and i get pdfLinks from html element.I am trying to download pdf files from a url like 'https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.09347'. Some of links doesnt work proper and i cant download all of them correct.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const https = require("https");
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const axios = require("axios");
const downloadPath =
  "C:\\Kodlamalar\\JavaScriptCodes\\WebScrapingProject\\public\\PDFFiles\\"; //i didnt use this but i will use

async function main() {
  const keyword = "machine learning"; //you can change this
  console.log(keyword);
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://scholar.google.com");

  await page.setViewport({ width: 1080, height: 1024 });

  await page.type('input[name="q"]', keyword);

  const submitBtn = await page.$("button[type=submit]");
  await submitBtn.evaluate((btn) => btn.click());
  await page.waitForNavigation();

  async function scrapeData(page) {
    const divs = await page.$$eval(".gs_r.gs_or.gs_scl", (divs) => {
      const results = [];
      //results are div objects
      divs.forEach((div) => {
        const hasPdfText = div.textContent.includes("PDF");
        if (hasPdfText) {
          const links = div.querySelectorAll(".gs_ri > h3 > a");
          links.forEach((link) => {
            results.push({
              text: link.textContent.trim(),
              href: link.getAttribute("href"),
            });
          });
          //another div objects to scrape pdfLinks
          const citations = div.querySelectorAll(".gs_fl.gs_flb > a");
          citations.forEach((citation) => {
            if (citation.textContent.includes("Alıntılanma sayısı")) {
              if (citation.textContent.trim()) {
                results.push({
                  divCitation: citation.textContent.trim(),
                });
              }
            }
          });
          const pdfLinks = div.querySelectorAll(".gs_or_ggsm > a");
          pdfLinks.forEach((link) => {
            results.push({
              pdfLink: link.getAttribute("href"),
            });
          });
        }
      });
      return results;
    });

    const titles = findTitles(divs);
    const urls = findUrls(divs);
    const citations = findCitations(divs);
    const pdfLinks = findPDFLinks(divs);

    return { titles, urls, citations, pdfLinks };
  }

  // Usage
  const { titles, urls, citations, pdfLinks } = await scrapeData(page);
  extractCitationNumber(citations);
  console.log(titles);
  console.log(urls);
  console.log(citations);
  console.log(pdfLinks);
  //There is a problem from this comment line
  const promises = pdfLinks.map((url, i) => {
    return downloadPDF(url, `example${i}.pdf`)
      .then(() => ({ status: "fulfilled" }))
      .catch((error) => ({ status: "rejected", reason: error }));
  });
  const allPromise = Promise.all(promises);
  try {
    const values = await allPromise;
    console.log(values);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  //to this line i tried download files at same time but some of them are corrupted
}
main();
function findTitles(divs) {
  const titles = [];
  divs.forEach(({ text }) => {
    if (text) {
      titles.push(text);
    }
  });
  return titles;
}
// Fonksiyon 2: Find URL Adress
function findUrls(divs) {
  const urls = [];
  divs.forEach(({ href }) => {
    if (href) {
      urls.push(href);
    }
  });
  return urls;
}
function findCitations(divs) {
  const citations = [];
  divs.forEach(({ divCitation }) => {
    if (divCitation) {
      citations.push(divCitation);
    }
  });
  return citations;
}
function findPDFLinks(divs) {
  const pdfLinks = [];
  divs.forEach(({ pdfLink }) => {
    if (pdfLink) {
      pdfLinks.push(pdfLink);
    }
  });
  return pdfLinks;
}
function extractCitationNumber(citations) {
  for (let i = 0; i < citations.length; i++) {
    citations[i] = citations[i].replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
  }
}

async function downloadPDF(url, destination) {
  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: url,
      responseType: 'stream'
    });

    const writer = fs.createWriteStream(destination);
    response.data.pipe(writer);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      writer.on('finish', resolve);
      writer.on('error', reject);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Error while downloading: ' + error.message);
  }
}
```

for example 7 of 4 pdf is correct and other 3 is corrupted`

Comment: @ggorlen you can compile now urls are coming from google chrome so if you change keyword machine learning to space you will get another pdf urls etc

Comment: Have you used a text editor to look into the corrupt files? These may be HTML(-Error) pages.

Comment: I have changed my downloadPDF code it works better but sometimes https response status code is 404 403 or something like this can i avoid this situation or it is impossible

Comment: @KJ so it is not my fault i cant do anything about situation